# Postgres text to array text in using insert

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, postgresql-9.5

I have a csv file which has column authors:

**test.csv**

```
authors 
authorA, authorB
```

Here, authors is the name of column and the values are authorA, authorB.

I have imported the data into the table test_author, which has structure as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_author(authors text);
```

Now, i want to transfer the data from this table to another table final using script and the database is postgres.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS final(authors text[]);
```

Here, authors is an array.

**script:**

```
for file in test.csv
do
    tail -n +2 $file > tempLoc
    PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -h postgres -U postgres postgres  \
      -c "\copy  test_author FROM 'tempLoc' delimiter ',' csv;"
done
```

When i execute the script, i get an error.

It transfers the data in test_author and i execute:

**transfer.sql**

```
INSERT INTO  final (authors)
SELECT
  authors
from final
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR:  column "authors" is of type text[] but expression is of type text
LINE 12:     authors,
             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

**So i have data in csv file i need to transfer that data to temp table which has field of type text using the script and finally into final table which has filed of type array. And i facing error, how can i resolve it? I would prefer to make the change in file transfer.sql preferably.**

Comment: You might then plan the upgrade nevertheless ;) - Postgres 9.5 will be EOL in about 7 months

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
INSERT INTO  final (authors)
SELECT
  authors:: text[]
from final;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to convert the comma separated string into an array when you copy the data, you can do using `string_to_array()`

```
INSERT INTO  final (authors)
SELECT string_to_array(authors, ',')
from test_author;
```

This would however keep the space after the `,` in `authorA, authorB`. You can avoid that by using `regexp_split_to_array()`

```
INSERT INTO  final (authors)
SELECT regexp_split_to_array(authors, '\s*,\s*')
from test_author;
```